# Dynamic edit rows in the table with AJAX

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, html-table

I have table with empty body:

```
<table id="tablem" border="1" width="100">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">PageName</th>
            <th style="width: 5%">Lang</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">ControlName</th>
            <th style="width: 70%">ControlValue</th>
            <th style="width: 5%">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I fill body by AJAX-request, which gets data from the database, and this Ajax-function construct table's body with data:

```
function ForSearching(args, callback) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/source_pages/SearchForMultilang.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: args,
}).success(function(data) {
    var table = $("#tablem tbody");
    $("#tablem tbody").empty();
    callback(data);
    $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
        table.append('<tr><td>' + elem.PageName + '</td><td>' + elem.Lang + '</td><td>' + elem.ControlName + '</td><td>' + elem.ControlValue + '</td><td><input type="button" id="btnedt" value="Edit" /></td></tr>');
    });
});
}
```

The table is created, filled by data, and in the last column Ajax creates Edit-button. 
When you click this button, textfield in every column in row must transform to `input type=text` with value from cell, so I can change value and after all save this changes in the selected row. And all this must work by ajax.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put this code witch changed selector in click handler of this button

```
$('td').each(function(){
   $(this).html($('<input>',{type:'text', value: $(this).html()}));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/urp83mtq/1/

EDIT: I just saw that you want have one button per row

```
$(':button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().children().each(function(){
            if($(this).children().length==0)
                    $(this).html($('<input>',{type:'text', value: $(this).html()}));
       });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/urp83mtq/2/